# Create External Javascript File on Server

Tags: javascript, html, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I have a javascript file javasc.js. I want to upload this file on some external server/domain. So that anyone can use it in their html file something like this:

```
<script src="external/url/to/javasc.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Can you please tell, how can this be done ?
(and how to obtain the external url of the file)

Comment: Do you want to upload this file dynamically? or you just want to host it on some CDN server?

Comment: kind of CDN server. but the file(which can be edited anytime) should be on my preferred domain.

Comment: Why not put it in github or something and simply point to the raw js? Or have I misunderstood the requirements here?

Comment: I want to keep the file on my preferred domain, if possible.

Comment: I can keep the file on github, but I want external url to contain this preferred domain name instead of 'github'.